# select item in getView method adapter spinner

Tags: android, adapter, android-spinner

i have spinner that i create with my custom adapter and i want to select specify item in load spinner and do not use setSelection method for select specify item because i use AsyncTask for load data to spinner.
write this code in adapter :

```
spinner.setSelection(myposition);
```

this method work but when click on spinner and chose an item, dropDown not hidden.

my question is how can i select item when i creating the items spinner.
i means how can i select item in the **getView** method in adapter?
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whe loading data in asyncTask (e.g for loop to fill arrayList) you can note the position you need to select and after adding all the data to adapter call the select method on spinner within same ayncTask (`postExecute`).

And why don't your drop down hiding are you overriding the click function of spinner ?

Comment: first of all i create an empty adapter.after that i fill data to adapter with AsyncTask then call a method that on this method i call         notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: now i want when i create items in getView function on adapter select the item

Comment: like when list opens up the last time selected item appears selected?

Comment: that you can do just after you called notifydatasetchanged. it will work

Comment: i useed setSelection in the getView method and after that when when click each item not set on spinner but when use this function after  notifyDataSetChanged it's work true